# Articles from the Journal of Recreational Mathematics from the 1970s

Tags: reference-request, puzzle, packing-problem

When reading some articles about packing puzzles I regularly stumble accros references from the "Journal of Recreational Mathematics" from the 1970s. I did not found any way of accessing these articles, since I cannot even locate the journal. Has anyone an idea how I could get these articles? In particular I am interested in

D. A. Klarner: Brick packing puzzles, J. Recreational Math. 6 (1973), 112-117

J. Haselgrove: Packing a square with Y-pentominoes, J. Recreational Math. 7 (1974), 229

J. Bitner: Tiling 5n x 12 rectangles with Y-pentominoes, J. Recreational Math. 7 (1974), 276-278.

Comment: I succeeded to find many universities near where I live whose libraries contain physical copies of this journal, which has been defunct since 2014. I suggest you check with the librarian at a university near where you live --- even if they don't have the journal, it is often the case that they can get copies via "inter-library loan".

Comment: A nonzero number of issues are available through sites like [Anna's archive](https://annas-archive.org/) when searching for "Journal of Recreational Mathematics" - looks like 1999-2000 and 2006, at least. Doesn't seem to have the articles you were looking for, though; your best bet might just be visiting a university library in person.